# Rails number_field_tag check at least one is not zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written following code to display a form with manny `number_field_tag`

```
<% @monsters.each do |monster| %>
  <tr>  
    <td><%= number_field_tag "monster[#{monster.id}][quantity]", 0, within: 0...10 %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Like this

[image]

How do I make sure at least one field is not zero?

Does Rails provide some magic feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 sides of validation: Directly in the frontend with JavaScript, or server side model validations.

Rails don't have any JavaScript feature for this, you have to do it yourself in JavaScript, e.g.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
    var foundQuantity = false;
    $('input[type*=quantity]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() > 0) { foundQuantity = true };
    ]);
    if (!foundQuantity) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Display some error somewhere
      $('.error-field').html("<div class='alert'>Please select at least one</div>");
    }
  });
```

For the server side: I see this is a combined form of many models? Did you have a parent model which holds the monsters? You can also only use Rails' validation on one model, not on many models. I would built a Form model for any form if there are more than one ActiveRecord-Model in it, like:

```
class MonsterForm
   include ActiveModel::Model
   attr_accessor :monsters
   validate :monster_quantity

   def monster_quantity
      if monsters.length == 0 || monsters.none?{|m| m.quantity > 0 }
        errrors.add(:monsters, "Need to have at least one..."
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do it both